# I killed my network! Help please :D

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04

As a newb, I have been playing with my setup. Now, I get a

```
waiting 60 seconds for network configuration
Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration
```

On boot and then when the UI is loaded the following errors appear:

```
Could not connect to wicd's D-Bus interface. Check the wicd log for error messages

The wicd daemon has shut down. The UI wpipll not function properly until it is restarted
```

I have searched the HDD for wicd.log nothing there.

I need to sort this out, so if anyone could help me to get my network back, I would love to give it a try.

## Edit

I run a Sony Vaio VGN-AR71E. 
Wireless network card connecting directly to the Internet via a wireless modem

Comment: Another Error is `Error connecting to wicd service via D-Bus`

Comment: 1. logfile should be /var/log/wicd 2. please confirm the upstart service for wicd is started. The 2nd one is probably not the case  (hence the error ;) )

Comment: Looked in /dev/ no log folder though

Comment: @Rinzwind sorry, no log file and I don't know how to see what services are running. But I think it can not be. How do I start it?

Comment: I'm trying now to find a network proxy that is not compatible with the system.

Answer (score 1):

My guess as to what you did wrong is you installed wicd and then after the installation was finished, you didn't completely remove the old network manager by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge network-manager-gnome network-manager
```

Therefore you've got two different conflicting network managers, and you can't connect to the internet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have just run that command and the results are the same as before. I think I need to delete the current network settings and reload the network manager, but I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Fixed it the hard way! Firstly I tried to repair the installation, that failed so I shifted everything important on to a separate HDD and wiped Ubuntu and reinstalled all the programmes again :) I should have finished adding all my email accounts (10) and contacts by 10am tomorrow. Thanks for your help.